Issue initializing Metadata extension
I have a instruction where I want to deploy a Token22 Mint and attach PermanateDelegate and Metadata extensions to it.
I want the metadata to be the mint itself.
My whole code works but fails in the last invoke_signed commented out
What am I missing?
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed;
use anchor_spl::token_2022::{spl_token_2022, Token2022};
use spl_token_2022::{
    extension::{
        metadata_pointer::{self},
        ExtensionType,
    },
    instruction::{self as token_2022_instruction},
    state::Mint as SplMint,
};

use crate::state::*;

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeWrappedToken<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        space = WrappedTokenMint::LEN,
        seeds = [
            b"wrapped_token", 
            abc.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub wrapped_token: Account<'info, WrappedTokenMint>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub abc: Account<'info, Abc>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            b"wrapped_token_mint", 
            abc.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
    )]
    pub mint: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
}

pub fn initialize_wrapped_token(ctx: Context<InitializeWrappedToken>) -> Result<()> {
    //...

    let wrapped_token = &mut ctx.accounts.wrapped_token;

    wrapped_token.abc = ctx.accounts.abc.key();
    wrapped_token.mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
    wrapped_token.authority = wrapped_token.key();

    let extension_types = vec![
        ExtensionType::PermanentDelegate,
        ExtensionType::MetadataPointer,
        //ExtensionType::TokenMetadata,
    ];

    let mint_len = ExtensionType::try_calculate_account_len::<SplMint>(&extension_types).unwrap();

    let rent = Rent::get()?;
    let required_lamports = rent.minimum_balance(mint_len);

    let mint_bump = ctx.bumps.mint;

    let abc_key = ctx.accounts.abc.key();

    let mint_seeds = &[b"wrapped_token_mint", abc_key.as_ref(), &[mint_bump]];
    let signer_seeds = &[mint_seeds.as_slice()];

    let create_account_ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::create_account(
        &ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
        &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
        required_lamports,
        mint_len as u64,
        &spl_token_2022::id(),
    );

    invoke_signed(
        &create_account_ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
        signer_seeds,
    )?;

    let init_permanent_delegate_ix = token_2022_instruction::initialize_permanent_delegate(
        &spl_token_2022::id(),
        &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
        &ctx.program_id,
    )?;

    invoke_signed(
        &init_permanent_delegate_ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
        signer_seeds,
    )?;

    let init_metadata_pointer_ix = metadata_pointer::instruction::initialize(
        &spl_token_2022::id(),
        &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
        Some(*ctx.program_id),
        Some(ctx.accounts.mint.key()),
    )?;

    invoke_signed(
        &init_metadata_pointer_ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
        signer_seeds,
    )?;

    let initialize_mint_ix = token_2022_instruction::initialize_mint2(
        &spl_token_2022::id(),
        &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
        &wrapped_token.key(),
        Some(&wrapped_token.key()),
        6,
    )?;

    invoke_signed(
        &initialize_mint_ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
        signer_seeds,
    )?;

    // let init_metadata_ix = spl_token_metadata_interface::instruction::initialize(
    //     &spl_token_2022::id(),
    //     &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
    //     &ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
    //     &ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
    //     &wrapped_token.key(),
    //     "METADATA".to_string(),
    //     "".to_string(),
    //     "".to_string(),
    // );

    // invoke_signed(
    //     &init_metadata_ix,
    //     &[
    //         ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
    //         ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
    //     ],
    //     signer_seeds,
    // )?;

    Ok(())
}

I am following more or less whats here: How do I get the new SPL token-metadata interface to work with SPL token-2022's metadata-pointer extension?
but as noticed, the last initialize is failing.

Maybe you could elaborate on what is the error your code throws and more exact stacktrace of the error to be easier to understand where could be the trouble?
